# How do I get my textboxes and buttons aligned which look like the picture?

Tags: html, css, margin

[image: Here is the image]

```css
.intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#para1 {
  padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px;
}

#para2 {
  padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
}

.username-label,
.username-textbox,
.password-label,
.password-textbox {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 400px;
}

#button1,
#button2 {
  background-color: #add8e6;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="~/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Project</title>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>

  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
    <div class="username-label">Username </div>
    <div class="username-textbox">
      <input class="existing username-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="password-label">Password</div>
    <div class="password-textbox">
      <input class="existing password-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <button id="button1">Log in</button>
    <hr />

    <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>
    <div class="Username-label1">Username: </div>
    <div class="username-textbox1">
      <input class="username-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="Password-label2">Password:</div>
    <div class="password-textbox2">
      <input class="password-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="Email-label3">Email:</div>
    <div class="email-textbox3">
      <input class="email-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="Repeat-Email-label4">Repeat Email Address:</div>
    <div class="repeat-email-textbox4">
      <input class="reenter-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <button id="button2">Create Account</button>

  </div>

  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I am having trouble with getting my textboxes and buttons aligned to look like the attached image. Can someone please also tell how I should make the radius border around my element smaller like the pic? Here is my code so far. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Image link is broken

Comment: The picture cannot be loaded.

Comment: Can't you just change the border-radius? (though i can't see the image the link is broken)

Comment: @ happymacarts can you see it now?

Comment: yes, i can see image now. Are we doing your Homework here? I think you may want to re-read how to use padding

Comment: @happymacarts, I need some help with understanding how I can align the textboxes to right top part like the image has it and how can get my border radius to be smaller without it taking the elements out of it?

Comment: google  the following css properties `float`s or `flexbox` you could also use `position`

Comment: @happymacarts- Can you embed the picture into this post so that everybody can see it?

Comment: just add an `!` like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: @happymacarts I don't have privilege to do that. I know how to do it. That's why I asked you but never mine someone else has already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Against my better judgement I went ahead and did your Homework :)

I wanted to show you an option using flexbox

here is a [great resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('doc is ready');

  $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-size: 12px;
}

.intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font: italic;
  font-style: italic;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content hr {
  width: 100%
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
}

form label span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

form label input {
 /* text-align: right;*/
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#para1,
#para2 {
  width: 40%;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}

button:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row top">
      <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
      <form id="login-form">
        <label class="username-label"><span>Username</span> <input class="existing username-input-textbox" type="text" value="" /></label>


        <label class="password-label"><span>Password</span> <input class="existing password-input-textbox" type="password" value="" /></label>

        <button id="button1">Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>
      <form id="create-form">

        <label class="Username-label1"><span>Username</span>  <input class="username-new-input-textbox" type="text"  /></label>

        <label class="Password-label2"><span>Password:</span><input class="password-new-input-textbox" type="password"  /></label>

        <label class="Email-label3"><span>Email:</span><input class="email-new-input-textbox" type="email"  /></label>

        <label class="Repeat-Email-label4"><span>Repeat Email Address:</span><input class="reenter-new-input-textbox" type="email"  /></label>

        <button id="button2">Create Account</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: @happymacarts-I never asked you do to my homework. I asked you questions about how to position certain elements. Don't get me wrong I appreciate everyone's contribution here, please never do this again.  Thanks anyway!!!!

Comment: sometimes just saying use `flexbox` wouldn't help much with providing an example. I only answered it because unlike other similar posts from other users, you showed some work and asked the question in a way that did not just want me to give the answer. Keep it up.

Comment: @ happymacarts-I am majoring in IT. I have always struggled with positioning elements in Web development. Do you know of any other good resources other than w3schools to get proficient at these types of concepts?

Comment: I find myself heading to [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/) often just be careful when using any source that is not a [reference guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) since sometimes they are out of date which are always easier to read than the [w3c](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/) guide

Comment: @happymacarts- Now that I took a good look at what you did I see that you use HTML forms. Forms won't be much helpful to me  when I have make call to the server using AJAX. But thanks anyway!!

Comment: why not? you can send whichever infomation you want in an ajax request. Semantically they should be in a form (yeah yeah i know they are not reqd) but explain why they won't work with ajax?